# Fit quantile regression. Different number of rows test/training

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, quantreg

I need to fit quantile regression to my data. I use code like this:

```
library(quantreg)
quantreg25 <- rq(Y ~ X, tau = 0.25)
P <- predict.rq(quantreg25, newdata=test)
```

However, I get error message:

> Warning message:
>       'newdata' had 60000 rows but variables found have 30000 rows

I have 30k rows in my training set, and like 60k in test set. Scriprt works, however, it creates only 30k values, not 60k expected. How may I fit and predict `Y` value in the test set using quantile regression here?

Comment: Works for me.  I suspect you have either something wrong with `test`, or the way you invoke `rq`.   How do you create `test`?  Can you show the head and the tail of it?

Comment: Can you be so kind to share how you create your datasets? I think I have problem with naming, e.g. function cant find vector to predict within test set.

Comment: Thank you. I've rerun this process with correct naming of vectors and everthing worked. Is it ok, that I have 0 values for dependent variable in test set before `predict`?

Comment: I think so, I guess only X will be used.  But just test it :-)  I created my test as `test <- data.frame(X=runif(200), Y=runif(200))`